# Move files to server

Tags: asp.net

How is it possible to move files from a folder to web server through FTP, using ASP.Net with C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chilkat do an FTP library which might make things easier for you.

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-2-dotnet.asp

My policy: if someone else has written it, use it - it'll have been tested better than your own code.